# Splitting strings into new variables

Tags: r, string, split, data.table

I have this data.table (an extract)

```
 DT <- data.table(ANNUAL = c("HR.PREN.B","HR.PREN.B06","HR.PREN.B081"),
       X2010 = c("102.1","121.2","92.5#s")
     )
```

from which I would like to generate

AREA as first part of the ANNUAL

INDIC as second part of ANNUAL

INDUS as third part of ANNUAL

I have tried to use strsplit with the [.] for splitting but it does not work out.
Furthermore when ready the values in X2010, I would like to extract the value (before the # sign) and then create a new variable cONF with what comes after the # (but here I guess I could use the same trick as for ANNUAL).
Thanks for your help

Comment: `DT[, c("AREA", "INDIC", "INDUS") := tstrsplit(ANNUAL, ".", fixed = TRUE)]`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `tidyverse` within `data.table` object

```
library(tidyverse)
setDT(DT[, .SD %>% 
             separate(ANNUAL, into = c("AREA", "INDIC", "INDUS")) %>%
             mutate(cONF = str_remove(X2010, "#.*"))])[]
#   AREA INDIC INDUS  X2010  cONF
#1:   HR  PREN     B  102.1 102.1
#2:   HR  PREN   B06  121.2 121.2
#3:   HR  PREN  B081 92.5#s  92.5
```